# Capture Device with Delphi (FireMonkey)

Tags: delphi, device, firemonkey, capture

I'm using Delphi-FireMonkey (TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultVideoCaptureDevice) to integrate a capture device to my system and I wonder how can I set TV channels on capture device with FireMonkey. Is there any way to do this?

My device is a AverMediaTV HD Pro USB (H868).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is out of the scope of the Firemonkey capturing device classes, you must ask to the manufacturer for a SDK for the capture device.

Comment: I asked the manufacturer about an SDK and does not exist. I will try another resource.

thanks.